# How to pass the node value as the attribute in Composite Component in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I am developing a JSF 2.0 composite component. I am trying to create a box component to which my required HTML will be set as attribute.

Some thing like..

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>#{cc.attrs.value}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</composite:implementation>
```

When I want to use this component and pass the required HTML to the attribute "value", like so:

```
<someDir:boxComp>Hello</someDir:boxComp>
```

the "Hello" is not taken as attribute value.
How i can make the node value as an attribute value.?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing it as tag attribute. You are just passing it as child in the tag body. In that case you need to use [`<composite:insertChildren />`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html) to insert it. So, instead of

```
<td>#{cc.attrs.value}</td>
```

you should be doing

```
<td><composite:insertChildren /></td>
```

---

**Or** if you *actually* want to use `#{cc.attrs.value}`, then you should be defining it as a *real* tag attribute from the beginning on instead of as tag body:

```
<someDir:boxComp value="Hello" />
```