# JSF2: How do I render composite component's children at a specific location within component?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have problem referencing and displaying composite component's childs like that:

```
<xyz:mycomponent>
  <h:outputText value="some text"/>
  <h:outputText value="another text"/>
</xyz:mycomponent>
```

Where `mycomponent` is defined like that:

```
<composite:implementation>
  <!-- some tags here -->
  <h:paneGroup>
    <!-- I want component's childs (two outputText's) to be rendered here -->
  </h:paneGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

I can list component's childs via `#{cc.children}` but I have no idea how to render them at a specific place of composite component. Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass the node value as the attribute in Composite Component in JSF 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090574/how-to-pass-the-node-value-as-the-attribute-in-composite-component-in-jsf-2-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<composite:insertChildren>` will do the trick.