# Can I template a h:dataTable?

Tags: java, jsf

Can I template a dataTable somehow, and just "inject" the variable + fields to display when implementing the template component?

Or do I always have to define

```
<dataTable>
<colums>
<text>
```

etc.

Comment: I's no clear to me what you mean by "template". Can you describe what concrete result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Michael: I'd guess he's talking about creating a custom Facelet tag or a composite component for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dov.amir's answer applies to JSF 1.2, really. If you're working with JSF 2.0 (I truly recommend that, by the way), you may want to take a look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: is it possible to define the count of components dynamically inside a composite? eg if I define a composite table, and do not know how many columns will be there. how can I define just 1 example column and feed it with as many parameters as needed?

Comment: Now that's a good question. I used to do that with JSF 1.2 and it works well, but I couldn't get it to work with JSF 2. After trying for a couple of hours, I said f#@$ it and just repeated the header for the tables. Since you seem to be using JSF 2, I am afraid I can't help you much. Let me know if you get this working... Cheers

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090574/how-to-pass-the-node-value-as-the-attribute-in-composite-component-in-jsf-2-0)

Comment: yo I also tried endlessly, but actually I'm just copypasting the headers and so on. you last post about insertChildren is just a placeholder for things occurring between the tags of the new custom composite component. which is quite interesting, nevertheless not of use for templating ;)

Answer (score 2):

it is posible but you need to create your own custem jsf tags,
I use this syntax

```
<mytag:table    backingBean="${myViewHandler}" 
                    ajax="true" 
                    maxColumnLength="50"                    
                    fields="dateTime,moduleName,methodName,arguments,returnValue,session.user.username"
                    maxPagesToDisplay="${10}">
        </mytag:table>
```

see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf4/